# having issue with PayPal express checkout

Tags: magento, paypal, express-checkout

I am having trouble with the PayPal express checkout.

After a custom coding it is working on product view page and cart page, but we are still facing issue to work it out at minicart and ajax cart pop up. Click event is not at all working there,

Is that possible to sort it out? Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Paypal Express buttons on the product view and cart page work out of the box. No custom coding is needed to make it work there.

Comment: You are right, but don't know someone has done coding like that and we were not getting link of paypal even on product view page, solved that  somehow but have 1 new issue. We are using ajax cart from magestore and when I click on paypal express from product view page, it adds 2 product qty instead of 1 and redirect to paypal.